# ¿Como lanzo eventos personalizados en java?

Tags: java, eventos

he estado investigando sobre como añadir eventos propios a clases, pero no he visto ningun ejemplo de mas de un evento, entonces he indagado en como lo tenia hecho la api de java, y este es mi resultado:

```
public class EventoUno extends EventObject{
    public EventoUno(Object source){
        super(source);
    }
}
public class EventoDos extends EventObject{
    public EventoDos(Object source){
        super(source);
    }
}
public interface EventoListener extends EventListener{
    public void eventoUnoOcurrio(EventoUno e1);
    public void eventoDosOcurrio(EventoDos e2);
}
public abstract class EventoAdapter implements EventoListener{
    public void eventoUnoOcurrio(EventoUno e1){}
    public void eventoDosOcurrio(EventoDos e2){}
}
public class Clase {

    EventListenerList ell = new EventListenerList();

public void addEventoUnoListener(EventoAdapter e1){
    ell.add(EventoListener.class, e1);
}

public void addEventoDosListener(EventoAdapter e2){
    ell.add(EventoListener.class, e2);
}

public void removeEventoUnoListener(EventoAdapter e1){
    ell.remove(EventoListener.class, e1);
}

public void removeEventoDosListener(EventoAdapter e2){
    ell.remove(EventoListener.class, e2);
}

    public void producirEventoUno(){

    }

    public void producirEventoDos(){

    }
}
public class app {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clase c = new Clase();
        c.addEventoUnoListener(new EventoAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void eventoUnoOcurrio(EventoUno e1) {
                System.out.println("Evento 1 ocurrio");
            }
        }
        );

        c.addEventoUnoListener(new EventoAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void eventoUnoOcurrio(EventoUno e1) {
                System.out.println("Evento 2 ocurrio");
            }
        }
        );

        c.producirEventoUno();
        c.producirEventoDos();
    }
}
```

La duda que tengo es como hago que salte el evento cuando ejecute producirEventoUno(), y producirEventoDos().

Gracias.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e1.eventoUnoOcurrio(new EventoUno());
```

No hay nada más, simplemente cuando tu lógica decide que tiene que señalizar un evento ejecuta el método adecuado del `listener`, pasando la información. Eso es lo que se llama "notificar" el evento.

Una cosa importante es que permitir un único `listener` es extraño y restringe mucho los posibles usos. Mantén una lista de `listeners`, de forma que cualquier componente que lo desee pueda añadir el suyo sin eliminar los que otros componentes hayan añadidos.

Relacionado con lo anterior, si un `listener` procesa varios eventos, no añadas el ´listener´ de manera distinta según que evento deba procesar, ya que eso complica todo. Sencillamente haz una única lista de `listeners`; los componentes que no estén interesados en el `eventoDos` simplemente dejarán la implementación vacía en el `listener` que registren.

De hecho, en general recomiendo seguir la práctica de tener un único evento por `listener`; el único caso en que encontraría aceptable -que no correcto- incluir la lógica de proceso de varios eventos en el mismo ´listener´ sería en el caso de que los eventos estuvieran intimamente ligados (por ejemplo, eventos de `borrarElemento` y `borrarTodosLosElementos` de una lista). Y aún así preferiría `listeners` separados.

Comment: Pero en new EventoUno(Object Source); que tendria que ponerle como parametro?

Comment: Ésa es la información que el controlador de eventos necesita para saber qué ocurrió, y dependerá del significado del evento. Por ejemplo, para `borrarElemento` igual puedes indicar el índice del elemento borrado y/o el propio elemento borrado, mientras que para `borrarTodosElementos` igual no hay información que pasar al `listener` y el método simplemente no acepta/necesita información.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad es muy sencillo: Realmente el patrón que estás intentando aplicar es el de Observable/Observador:

Tienes una clase que lanza un evento y quieres que sea observable. En tu caso sólo acepta un observador, pero podrías cambiarla para guardar una lista de observadores. Entonces, cuando quieras producir un evento, recorres la lista de observadores y llamas a sus métodos. En tu caso:

```
void producirEventoUno() {
    if (e1!=null) {
        e1.eventoUnoOcurrio();
    }
}
```

Si tuvieras una lista de observadores, en un caso genérico:

```
class MiClaseObservable {

    List<Observador> observadores= new ArrayList<>();

    void addObservador(Observador o) {
        observadores.add(o);
    }

    void lanzarEvento() {
        observadores.forEach(obs -> obs.eventoOcurrido());
    }
}
```

PS: A quien pueda interesar, la pregunta equivalente en SO en inglés es [ésta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270132/create-a-custom-event-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

Aunque es una discusión antigua es interesante recuperarla para dejar un ejemplo de implementación de eventos y listeners personalizados, como bien había empezado https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/17359/tlaloc-es

Conforme a la documentación de Java los eventos: producirEventoUno y producirEventoDos podrían estar definidos de la siguiente manera:

```java
public void producirEventoUno() {
        EventoUno e1 = new EventoUno(this);

        // Se garantiza que devuelve un array no nulo
        Object[] listeners = ell.getListenerList();

        // Procesa los oyentes de último a primero, notificando a
        // a los que están interesados en este evento
        for (int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            if (listeners[i] == EventoListener.class) {
                ((EventoListener) listeners[i + 1]).eventoUnoOcurrio(e1);
            }
        }

    }

    public void producirEventoDos() {
        EventoDos e2 = new EventoDos(this);

        // Se garantiza que devuelve un array no nulo
        Object[] listeners = ell.getListenerList();

        // Procesa los oyentes de último a primero, notificando a
        // a los que están interesados en este evento
        for (int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            if (listeners[i] == EventoListener.class) {
                ((EventoListener) listeners[i + 1]).eventoDosOcurrio(e2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y la clase App.java corregida sería:

```java
public class app {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clase c = new Clase();
        c.addEventoUnoListener(new EventoAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void eventoUnoOcurrio(EventoUno e1) {
                System.out.println("Evento 1 ocurrio");
            }
        }
        );

        c.addEventoDosListener(new EventoAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void eventoDosOcurrio(EventoDos e2) {
                System.out.println("Evento 2 ocurrio");
            }
        }
        );

        c.producirEventoUno();
        c.producirEventoDos();
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo de perfil lo acabo de actualizar. Respecto al formato de stackoverflow, te agradezco la aclaración pero he empleado incorrectamente la palabra "hilo" para referirme a la "discusión", aunque conozco el funcionamiento de la web. 

Como veo que te gusta el uso correcto y estricto del lenguaje, te comento que cuando dices "...no está demás" es incorrecto y debe emplearse "...no está de más" https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/de-mas-demas/